# Cross threading issue updating data source

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading

**Goal:**

Once i click on the start button on my user interface, i currently fire two background workers.

BGWorker 1 is responsible for invoking the .dll method to crawl a website
BGWorker 2 is responsible for updating the DataGridView using the Datasource = source setter

**Issues:**

My dll receives as argument, the reference to the Data Source that will be populated while the .dll is running. So Basically, the .dll is going to add a object in the data source once in a while, until it finishes running.

The BGWorker 2 does this :

```
while (1 == 1) // Runs until is it manually disposed
{
    CoursesGrid.BeginInvoke // inline method 
    (
        (Action) delegate 
        {
            if (_coursesSource.Count > 0) // if source is not empty,Binds.
            {
                try
                { 
                    CoursesGrid.DataSource = _coursesSource;
                    CoursesGrid.EndEdit();
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    Logs.LogWriter.LogError(ex);
                }                   
            }
            else
            {
                // Signals User To keep Waiting
            }
        }
     );
Thread.Sleep(4000);
```

**Behavior flow:**

- Dll is Invoked
- Method Parses a element and adds to the source
- Eventually, BGWorker 2 Wakes up and Binds the DataGridView source to the modified Source
- Dll threads keep parsing but fails once it tries to add a new element to the source

**TL:DR:**
Thread 1 Writes on the Source
Thread 2 Reads this modified source, and binds it to the DataGridView to it will refresh
Thread 1 Fails to write again on the source :

```
"Cross-thread operation not valid: Control 'CoursesGrid' accessed from a thread other than the thread it was created on."}
```

Both threads are handling the same source, but the BGWorker 2, only binds it to the interface, this should be working. Any idea of what might be happening here?

Comment: I'm guessing something is not working the way you want, maybe you could tell us what is or isn't working and what the errors are.

Comment: btw, fyi, In C# 3.0 you can write just `BeginInvoke(() => { ... })`

Comment: @CodingGorilla Edited. Sorry if it wasn't clear in the first time.
Added a TL:DR

Comment: What is `_coursesSource' and does this exception *only* happen after the first update (ie. it doesn't happen on the initial bind, only after a second row is added)

Comment: @CodingGorilla Yes, only after the first insertion in the datasource.
_coursesSource is the DataSource passed as argument to the .dll, and the same reference to the datasource that BGWorker 2 uses to bind on the Data Grid View ( CoursesGrid )

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think what is happening is that you are binding the data grid to your `_coursesSource` which causes the data grid to show the first row.  Then, later, you are modifying **the same** `_coursesSource` instance which likely fires a property change or collection change notification which causes the data grid to attempt to update itself (ie. show the newly added row).

But since the modification is happening on another thread the event which the data grid "hears" and responds to also happens on that background thread which causes the cross thread violation.

What you need to do, is either a) marshal the add to `_coursesSource` onto the UI thread (which it doesn't sound like you  can easily do), or b) bind to a copy of `_coursesSource` and then in your BGWorker 2, each time you update `_coursesSource` re-bind the grid to a new copy, that way the grid is never "hearing" change notifications, it's always just binding to a fresh copy of the collection.  It's not the most efficient way to do things, but it should get the job done for you.

Comment: Just tried the second approach.
On BGWorker 2, i get the reference to the _coursesSource, copy it to a "temp" BindingSource, and binds the GridView to the "temp" BindingSource.

Still have the same problem.
Any other approach you might think ?

Comment: Can you update your post with the new code and indicate specifically where the exception happens?

Comment: How is `ParseCourse` called?  I can see where that appears to be accessing the control, so if it's not being called from the UI thread then that's your problem.

Comment: I managed to make it work.
I will accept your answer as the correct.

This is how i "invoke" the .dll : CoursesGrid.Invoke((Action)  delegate {_bgCrawler.RunWorkerAsync(input);});

I used the Second approach you gave me.
Thanks

Comment: @MarcelloGrechiLins If you don't mind/have the time, update your pastebin, I'd be curious to see how you fixed it.

Comment: There you are. http://pastebin.com/NdRmtfQF

This is the code that might be useful, the rest is just method calls.